# Numpy ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,4) (3,3)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am getting the error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,4) (3,3)

```
z= np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
m= np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
z * m
```

error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,4) (3,3)

Comment: which is the line that raise the error? it seems like you are trying to add one to the other, but they have different shape

Comment: when i try to multiply these two then i got error @MatteoPeluso

Comment: Which result do you expect to get when multiplying arrays of different dimesions?

Comment: The * operator provides elementwise multiplication, which requires that the arrays are the same shape, or are 'broadcastable'. Use `np.dot(z, m)` in your case

Comment: Why do you think they should multioly?  Do you know the basics of numpy broadcasting?

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np
z= np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
m= np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

print(np.dot(m,z))
## [[ 20  23  26  29]
## [ 56  68  80  92]
## [ 92 113 134 155]]

print(np.dot(z.T,m))
##[[ 60  72  84]
##[ 69  84  99]
##[ 78  96 114]
##[ 87 108 129]]
```

Comment: He's not using `dot`.  Dot doesn't raise broadcasting errors.

Comment: thanks @prudhvi it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

to be able to multiply those matrices they should share the same dimension along the multiplication:

Z[3x4] * M[3x3] is not possible to evaluate because you have four columns on the Z matrix

to be able to multiply it you should or build differently your z matrix or translate it

in this example I translate the dimension of the matrix before doing the multiplication:  Z[4x3] * M[3x3] = ZM[4x3]:

`np.dot(z.T, m)`